# функция replaceWith jQuery не подменяет элемент

Tags: jquery

Задача такая: при выборе из select значения select должен превратиться в label с текстом из select и рядом кнопка "Изменить". Если нажать на "Изменить" label и кнопка опять превращаются в select. Первое превращение работает, а по кнопке нет. Что я делаю неправильно?

HTML:

```
<select id="select_customer" data-placeholder="Покупатель" tabindex="2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    </select>
```

JS:

```
$("#select_customer").change(function (){
    var sp = $("#select_customer :selected").text();            
    var $span = $('<h3><span class="label label-primary">' + sp +'</span><button id="choose_customer" type="button" class="btn btn-default">  Изменить</button></h3>')

$("#select_customer").select2('destroy').replaceWith($span);             
});     


$("#choose_customer").click(function(){
   $span.replaceWith($("#select_customer").select2());      
    })
```

;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2() тут роли не играет. его можно выкинуть. Я сделала так: 
1. после загрузки документа запомнила select в переменную

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cust=$('#select_customer');
```

при изменении select создается метка и кнопка, селект ими заменяется, а на кнопку вешается событие методом **on** по которому должно обратно все замениться select (моей переменной cust).

```
$("#select_customer").change(function (){
    var sp = $("#select_customer :selected").text();
    var $span = $('<h3><span class="label label-primary">' + sp +'</span>     <button id="choose_customer" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Изменить</button></h3>')
   cust.replaceWith($span);
   $("#choose_customer").on('click',function(){
       $span.replaceWith(cust);
       cust.on('change');//к селекту привязываю событие
       });
   });
```

т.к. select заново создан событие change не приязано к нему. Я пытаюсь его привязать. но оно не привязывается. Метка заменяется обратно select, но при его изменении уже ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что событие `$("#choose_customer").click()` присваивается при создании страницы, когда объекта `$("#choose_customer")` еще не существует. Он появляется позже, но событие к нему уже не привязано.

Предлагаю сменить "позывные" кнопки, а также привязку события...

```
var $span = $('<h3><span class="label label-primary">' + sp +'</span><button type="button" class="choose_customer btn btn-default">  Изменить</button></h3>')
```

а событие привязать не к кнопке, а к документу.

```
$("body .choose_customer").click(function(){
   $span.replaceWith($("#select_customer").select2());
});
```

Из-за компоненты `select2()` проверить точность ответа не могу, но, думаю, общее направление решения указал :)

Comment: ваш ответ не работает, но напраление вы действительно указали. спасибо!